# Unable to delete multiple record

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have write code to delete multiple record in gridview but it only delete one record in gridview. Could someone help me to solve this problem. Here is my code

```
 'This is to Delete multiple records in gridview
Private Sub DeleteMultipleRecords(ByVal idCollection As StringCollection)
    'Create sql Connection and Sql Command
    Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
    Dim IDs As String = ""

    'Create string builder to store 
    'delete commands separated by ;

    For Each id As Integer In idCollection
        IDs += id & ","
    Next
    Try
        Dim test As Integer = IDs
        Dim sql As String = "DELETE FROM [1BK] WHERE [sampleID] in (" & test & ")"
        Dim ANS As Integer
        ANS = MsgBox("Are you sure want to delete selected record ?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If ANS = vbYes Then
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            cmd.Connection = cnnOLEDB
            cnnOLEDB.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
        ANS = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim errorMsg As String = "Error in Deletion"
        errorMsg += ex.Message
        Throw New Exception(errorMsg)
    Finally
        cnnOLEDB.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not deleting records in a GridView, you are deleting records in a database.  Are they being deleted?  Maybe you just need to rebind (refresh) the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

The test variable should be a `string` as you are using `IN` clause.
For Example

```
string test="'1','2'"
if(test=="")
 test = "'" & id & "'"
else
 test += "," & "'" & id & "'"
```

Then the query will work

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
IDs+= "'"&id &"'" & ","
```

instead of

```
IDs += id & ","
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code.

```
//Dim test As Integer
Dim test As String
```

test is a string value, not integer.

And when you finished

```
IDs += id & ","
```

The last "," should by removed.

So you should add one more line code after finishing your loop.

```
IDs = IDs.TrimEnd(',')
```